# Is O(n) greater than O(2^log n)

Tags: math, optimization, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I read in a data structures book complexity hierarchy diagram that n is greater than 2<sup>log n</sup>. But cannot understand how and why. On using simple examples in power of 2 as n, I get values equal to n.

It is not mentioned in book , but I am assuming it to base 2 ( as context is DS complexity)

> a) Is `O(n) > O(pow(2,logn))`?
>
> b) Is `O(pow(2,log n))` better than `O(n)`?

Comment: i think they are the same.

Comment: Take the log of both. Conclude.

Comment: they are the same even if the logarithm base is different from 2.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that 2<sup>log<sub>b</sub> n</sup> = 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub> n / log<sub>2</sub> b</sup> = n<sup>(1 / log<sub>2</sub> b)</sup>. If log<sub>2</sub> b ≥ 1 (that is, b ≥ 2), then this entire expression is strictly less than n and is therefore O(n). If log<sub>2</sub> b < 1 (that is, b < 2), then this expression is of the form n<sup>1 + ε</sup> and therefore not O(n). Therefore, it boils down to what the log base is. If b ≥ 2, then the expression is O(n). If b < 2, then the expression is ω(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, it means both are equal and we can not say one is better than other for b=2?

Comment: when we talk of log in DS complexity in general, do we always refer to it with base 2?

Comment: @HimanshuR Logarithms are *usually* base-2 in computer science, though you shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: Strict inequality is only for b > 2, not b >= 2 as in this answer, as @HimanshuR rightly remarks.

Comment: I'm bad at math so I can't tell how you got from `2^(log2(n)/log2(b))` to `n^(1/log2(b))`.

Comment: No worries! It’s a two-step process. First use the fact that a^(b/c) = (a^b)^(1/c). Then use the fact that 2^(log_2 n) = n.

Answer (score 2):

There is a constant factor in there somewhere, but it's not in the right place to make O(n) equal to O(pow(2,log n)), assuming `log` means the natural logarithm.

```
n = 2 ** log2(n)            // by definition of log2, the base-2 logarithm
  = 2 ** (log(n)/log(2))    // standard conversion of logs from one base to another
n ** log(2) = 2 ** log(n)   // raise both sides of that to the log(2) power
```

Since log(2) < 1, `O(n ** log(2)) < O(n ** 1)`. Sure, there is only a constant ratio between the exponents, but the fact remains that they are different exponents. `O(n ** 3)` is greater than `O(n ** 2)` for the same reason: even though 3 is bigger than 2 by only a constant factor, it is bigger and the Orders are different.

We therefore have

```
O(n) = O(n ** 1) > O(n ** log(2)) = O(2 ** log(n))
```

Just like in the book.

Comment: Doesn't 2^(log_2 n) = n, rather than n ^ ln 2?

Comment: @templatetypedef: ganbustein is assuming a natural logarithm, rather than a binary logarithm.