# Recurrence Relation and Time Complexity for finding height of binary tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, big-o, recurrence

I am working on a simple problem of finding height of a binary tree on HackerRank. My solution below passed all test cases and after some running code by hands, I believe it is an O(n) solution. Most other solutions I found online (I think) said it is O(n) as well, but I am unable to solve the recurrence relation to reach O(n) based on both solutions.

Assuming the tree is not balanced, below is my solution:

```
 public static int height(Node root) {
    // Write your code here.
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
      return 0;
    } else if (root.left == null && root.right != null) {
      return 1 + height(root.right);
    } else if (root.left != null && root.right == null) {
      return 1 + height(root.left);
    } else {
      return 1 + Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right));
    }
  }
```

I found that the number of functions called is almost exact the number of nodes, which means it should be O(n). Based on my last case, which I think is likely to be the worst runtime case when I need to call height(node) on both branches, I tried to derive the following recurrence relation

```
Let n be the number of nodes and k be the number of level
T(n) = 2 T(n/2)

Base Case: n = 0, n =1

T(0) = -1
T(1) = T(2^0)= 0

Recursive Case:
k = 1, T(2^1) = 2 * T(1)
k = 2, T(2^2) = 2 * T(2) = 2 * 2 * T(1) = 2^2 T(1)
k = 3, T(2^3) = 2^3 * T(1)
....
2^k = n=> k = logn => T(2^k) = 2^k * T(1) = 2^logn * T(1)
```

So to me apparently, the time complexity is `O(2^logn)`, I am confused why people say it is O(n) ? I read this article ([Is O(n) greater than O(2^log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387198/is-on-greater-than-o2log-n)) and I guess it makes sense because `O(n) > O(2^logn)`, but I have two questions:

1. Is my recurrence relation correct and the result correct ? If it is, why in reality ( I count the number of times function is called) I still get O(n) instead of O(2^logn) ?
2. How do you derive recurrence relation for a recursive function like this ? Do you take the worst case (in my case is last condition) and derive recurrence relation from that ?

Comment: It's not a bad exercise to work out the recurrence, but for this problem it's not necessary. The search visits each node and expends constant time per node. Consequently it must be Omega(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `2^log(n) = n` based on the definition of the `log` function, you can find that both are the same. it means `O(n)` and `O(2^log(n))` are equivalent.

Also if you need to find the height of the tree repeatedly, you can preprocess the tree and store the height of subtree for each node to find the height of the tree in `O(1)` after the preprocessing phase.

Comment: precisely `log` means logarithm to the base `2`. So `2^log(n) = x => log(n).log(2) = log(x) => log(n) = log(x) => x = n. Therefore O(2^log(n)) = O(n)` - just wanted to add explanation.